# ROOT_URL is not defined | Pushing is causing a build failure

Tags: heroku, meteor

**If I go to the the build log I see the following:**

```
-----> Node.js app detected

FATAL: ROOT_URL is not defined.

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.

 !     Push failed
```

**This is what I am getting in my terminal:**

```
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: FATAL: ROOT_URL is not defined.
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to virtually-viral.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/virtually-viral.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/virtually-viral.git'
```

NOTE: I do not know what to do to fix this and get my app working, I have checked multiple discussions on people having a somewhat similar problem but I was not able to fix it with their solutions.

Comment: Have you configured your application to use a `ROOT_URL` environment variable? Does the code run locally with `heroku local`?

Comment: This is what happens when I run Heroku local                                                 [WARN] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Procfile'
[OKAY] package.json file found - trying 'npm start'
[WARN] ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'Procfile'
[OKAY] package.json file found - trying 'npm start'
6:21:57 AM web.1 |  /bin/sh: npm: command not found
[DONE] Killing all processes with signal  SIGINT
6:21:57 AM web.1 Exited with exit code null

Comment: You don't have `npm` installed locally? Do you have `yarn`? Node.js itself? How are you developing your application if you don't have these tools? Try getting your app on its feet locally before deploying to Heroku.

Comment: @Chris I just installed Node.JS and NPM, and I am still having the same problem, when enter heroku local it says that it cannot find the procfile but it still runs it locally successfully. I also tried to push to master to heroku but it still has the same problem which is in my post.

Comment: Have you set any environment variables locally, either directly or via something like an `.env` file? Or maybe in your IDE?

Comment: @Chris No, I do not use an IDE, I just use Visual Studio Code with my terminal on MacOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know much about Meteor so I'm not sure why this works in development, nor can I find any canonical list of critical settings that are required for it to work. The closest I can find is the documentation for [`Meteor.absoluteUrl`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-absoluteUrl) (bold added):

> Generate an absolute URL pointing to the application. The server reads from the `ROOT_URL` environment variable to determine where it is running. This is taken care of automatically for apps deployed to Galaxy, but **must be provided when using `meteor build`**.

You should be able to get past this issue by [setting the `ROOT_URL` variable on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars), e.g.

```
heroku config:set ROOT_URL=https://virtually-viral.herokuapp.com
```

or through the web interface.